# Git and Chef Best Practices

Tags: git, chef-infra, devops

I'm organizing a Chef repo and had a question about best practices.  I noticed that generating both the Chef Project and a Cookbook act like they are going to each be added to a Git repo in what they generate.

What I wanted to know is it best to have the cookbook in it's own Git Repo or should it be part of a larger Project Repo?  Should a Project even be added to Git?  Why does it the chef tool generate overlapping boilerplate?

Thanks,
RB

Comment: This is a very opinion based question. I know if it's appropriate to ask it here. Although I don't know where else you could...

Comment: @evolutionxbox Probably on chef's Slack ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current recommendation is a primarily mono-repo based solution, but pulling in community cookbooks (or cross-team cookbooks) via Policyfiles from their own repos (or from Supermarket). https://github.com/poise/yolover-example is an example with some local cookbooks, policies, and tests.

The reason for the multitude of conflicting templates in `chef generate` is mostly just that Chef workflows and layouts have a long and complex history, so we want the tools to continue to work for people using older workflows as long as they are still happy with them. But if you are getting started now, might as well start with the current best recommendations.